# What's the purpose of the 3rd argument in useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization):

> [init, the 3d argument] lets you extract the logic for calculating the initial state outside the reducer. This is also handy for resetting the state later in response to an action.

And the code:

```js
function init(initialCount) {
  return { count: initialCount };
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case 'reset':
      return init(action.payload);
    ...
  }
}

function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialCount, init);
  ...
}
```

Why would I do that over reusing a constant `initialState`?

```js
const initialState = {
  count: 5,
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case 'reset':
      return initialState;
    ...
  }
}

function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  ...
}
```

Looks less verbose to me.

Comment: If you are asking why they provide a seemingly useless API, the answer is lazy initialization. It’s just a nice-to-have feature. And since the useReducer hook is apparently taken from Redux, why wouldn’t they keep API consistent.

Comment: Gotcha. But isn't the state initialised with the default values anyway? `initialCount` is still present as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Yep it’s up to you to pick either one of 2 usages. I think the doc is pretty clear, [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: Sorry, what I asked is whether the initial state is set even if you set the 3rd argument? If the answer is no, I guess this is what you mean by lazy loading. that is, the user must dispatch a `reset` update for the initial count to be set, otherwise the `count` is null?

Comment: You get it wrong. Case 1, `useReducer(reducer, 0)` then init count is 0. Case 2 `useReducer(reducer, 7, n => 2 * n)`, then init count is 14. Is that clear?

Comment: I think you should probably setup a code base to test these sorts of things out when unsure. I got a good source for you. [TNG-Hooks](https://github.com/getify/TNG-Hooks/blob/master/src/tng-hooks.src.js) read this source code. It’ll greatly improve you knowledge about react hooks.

Comment: Thanks @hackape the example with `n => 2 * n` clarified it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

EDIT july 2020: [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization) has now better explainations on this arg called `lazy initializer`. Using this function in another way could result to breaking changes due to undocumented effect. Following answer remain valid.

---

As far as I can experiment, the `init` function as third arg is a transformer of the `initialState`.

It means that `initialState` will not be used a initial state, but as arg for `init` function. The return of this one will be the true `initialState`. It could be usefull to avoid huge param during the `useReducer` initialization line.

```js
/* Here is the magic. The `initialState` pass to 
 * `useReducer` as second argument will be hook
 * here to init the real `initialState` as return
 * of this function
 */
const countInitializer = initialState => {
  return {
    count: initialState,
    otherProp: 0
  };
};

const countReducer = state => state; // Dummy reducer

const App = () => {
  const [countState /*, countDispatch */] =
    React.useReducer(countReducer, 2, countInitializer);

  // Note the `countState` will be initialized state direct on first render
  return JSON.stringify(countState, null, 2);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be marked as accepted, imo. @developerKumar's statement is wrong (it does work, but it's wrong), it's not an initial action, but an initial state transformer, indeed.

Comment: @AlexanderKim if you're interested I've upgrade my answer in order to be more explicit

Answer (score 10):

My understanding is that the lazy initialization is designed for special situations that the code initializing the state is memory-intensive or CPU-intensive so the developer wants to keep the scope of the state data inside the component.

For example, if you are going to design a PhotoPane component which holds a high definition photo for editing.

```
const PhotoPane = (props) => {
    const initialPixelData = loadPhoto(props.photoID);
    const [pixelData, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFunc, initialPixelData);
    ...
}
```

Above code has a serious performance issue because `loadPhoto()` is repeatedly called. If you don't want to load the photo again every time when the component renders, the intuitive reaction is to move the `loadPhoto(props.photoID)` out of the component. But it will cause another problem. You will have to load all photos into memory in Context or somewhere else and it will definitely create a memory hog.

So this is the time for us to introduce lazy initialization. Please check out the code below.

```
const PhotoPane = (props) => {
    const init = (photoID) => loadPhoto(photoID);
    const [pixelData, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFunc, props.photoID, init);
    ...
}
```

The `init()` function is executed exactly only one time when the `useReducer` is first called.

Actually `useEffect()` hook can achieve a similar result. But lazy initialization is still the most direct solution.

Answer (score 7):

useReducer accepts an optional third argument, initialAction. If provided, the initial action is applied during the initial render.

For example:

```
function Counter({ initialCount }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState, {
    type: "reset",
    payload: initialCount
  });
```

As you can see, the third parameter is an initial action to be performed, applied during the initial render.

For Example: [Codesandbox Example Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/olxp9qw68z)

Comment: I still don't understand since the doc says : `It lets you extract the logic for calculating the initial state outside the reducer. This is also handy for resetting the state later in response to an action` . With a function as example.

Comment: I don't think this is right.More info here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization

Comment: This is not correct, from documentation:  You can also create the initial state lazily. To do this, you can pass an init function as the third argument. The initial state will be set to init(initialArg). https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way of understanding `useReducer` is to `useState` as an example where `useState` has an initial value or lazy initializer.

```
import { Dispatch, useReducer } from "react";
export function useStateUsingReducer<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<S>] {
  if (typeof initialState === "function") {
    return useReducer(
      (state: S, newState: S) => (Object.is(state, newState) ? state : newState),
      null as unknown as S,
      initialState as () => S
    );
  } else {
    return useReducer(
      (state: S, newState: S) => (equals(state, newState) ? state : newState),
      initialState
    );
  }
}
```

And a more practical version of this one is to do deep equals as `useState` only goes as far as `Object.is`.

```
import { equals } from "ramda";
import { Dispatch, useReducer } from "react";
export function useDeepState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<S>] {
  if (typeof initialState === "function") {
    return useReducer(
      (state: S, newState: S) => (equals(state, newState) ? state : newState),
      null as unknown as S,
      initialState as () => S
    );
  } else {
    return useReducer(
      (state: S, newState: S) => (equals(state, newState) ? state : newState),
      initialState
    );
  }
}
```